# frequency/phase offset estimation in satellite DOA beamforming applications

Tags: digital-communications, beamforming, spectrum-estimation

In satellite QPSK demodulation, we first estimate and remove the phase offset introduced by the channel. Then, we demodulate the baseband information bits (I & Q channels).

In satellite DOA beamforming, Channel can also introduce phase / frequency offset. When we detect the desired signal from a certain direction in the frequency domain (spectrum), how could we detect this channel introduced phase / frequency offset?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you distribute a mixing oscillator to all ground stations, so that their respective phase is known and can hence be corrected upfront. Having known phase between these receiver parts typically requires a lot of RF design effort and external phase calibration.

Comment: We adjust antenna array's weights to receive signals from the desired direction while suppressing interference from other directions. Is there a more practical way to estimate the phase offset introduced by the channel in all directions?

Comment: well, that boils down to channel estimation – there's a million ways to do that, and it all depends on your application and the knowledge you have about the signal you want to receive.